# Как получить только первый элемент (без display: none)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

в данном случае

```html
<p class="error" style>текст 3</p>
```

```html
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 1</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 2</p>
<p class="error" style>текст 3</p>
<p class="error" style>текст 4</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 5</p>
<p class="error" style>текст 6</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 7</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 8</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery предоставляет селектор [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) позволяющий выбрать видимые элементы.

Видимыми элементами считаются элементы, занимающие какое-либо пространство в документе.

Из полученной выборки достаточно получить первый элемент:

```js
console.log($('.error:visible').eq(0).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 1</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 2</p>
<p class="error" style>текст 3</p>
<p class="error" style>текст 4</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 5</p>
<p class="error" style>текст 6</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 7</p>
<p class="error" style="display: none">текст 8</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const getElement = (position) => {  
  const errorsNode = document.querySelectorAll('.error');  
  const errors = [...errorsNode]; 
  
  const filterElements = errors.filter(element => element.style.display === ''); 
  return filterElements[position];
 }  
 
 console.log(getElement(0));
```

```html
 <body>
    <p class="error" style="display: none">текст 1</p>
    <p class="error" style="display: none">текст 2</p>
    <p class="error" style>текст 3</p>
    <p class="error" style>текст 4</p>
    <p class="error" style="display: none">текст 5</p>
    <p class="error" style>текст 6</p>
    <p class="error" style="display: none">текст 7</p>
    <p class="error" style="display: none">текст 8</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```